# prepared statement while loop error php

Tags: php, mysqli

```
public function suggest(){
$SQL = "SELECT CategoryName FROM tb_category WHERE CategoryName LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')";
$stmt = $this->_db->mysqli->prepare($SQL);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $this->querystring);
$stmt->execute();
$meta = $stmt->result_metadata();  
while($field = $meta->fetch_field())
    {     
     $parameters[] = &$row[$field->name];
     //print_r($parameters); 
    }
```

In my `while`-loop its giving the on thing again and again just checking the single row in db not the whole table I guess there isn't any problem with like operator here

Comment: I would double check your query by outputting it before the query is executed - and then double check the results it produces by running it manually (using PHPMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench or something similar)

Comment: i doubt this returns anything useful .. `$row` isn't even defined in the functions scope. Did you paste the full code or did you possibly strip important parts?

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure i understood well:

```
while($field = $meta->fetch_field())
{     
 $parameters[] = &$row[$field->name];
 //print_r($parameters); 
}
```

Suppose you query returns 10 rows, does this while execute 10 times?

Try `$row[$field->name];` instead of `&$row[$field->name];` (without `&`)

finally `fetch_field()` returns the definitions of the columns you retreived with your query. As you select only `CategoryName` you are printing only `CategoryName` column definitions